# How to compare text pattern in SAS Studio?

Tags: replace, sas, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, regexp-replace

I am doing code migration from Teradata SAS to Snowflake SAS Studio.
The goal is to compare whether 2 text sentences are similar, for example

```
column_1: 'I want to eat 100 apples!'

column_2: 'I want to eat 20 apples!'
          'I want to eat 100 bananas!'
```

In this case the number of fruits I want to eat doesn't matters, I want to find matching cell for 'I want to eat apples'. Therefore 'I want to eat 20 apples!' should be my result.

Originally in Teradata SQL we combined  RegExp_Replace and Oreplace to do the trick, but it seems the  RegExp_Replace function changed in SAS Studio.

Any suggestions?
Many thanks!

Comment: What interface you use to run your SAS code (SAS/Studio) should not matter.  What is important is the version of actual SAS you are running and what database (if any) is housing the data.  Are you still using Teradata to store the data or not?  If not then you cannot use Teradata specific extensions to SQL syntax.  If you switched to a different database then check what syntax that database supports.

Comment: Hi Tom, we have switched to snowflake as our database

Comment: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions-regexp.html

Comment: If you're looking for a scoring with respect to comparing text strings, I would recommend you look into the jarowinkler_similarity function released earlier this year in Snowflake:  https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/jarowinkler_similarity.html